# Installing gcc in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, apt, sudo, software-sources, mirrors

I want to install `gcc` on my computer. To do this, I [ran the following command](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1017379/):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

As this runs, it connects (or tries to connect) to the server `tw.archive.ubuntu.com`. But the server is not working.

How can I fix this and get `gcc` installed?

---

Note: the Taiwan mirror is down as of 2012-06-01 0352. See [thread here](http://www.ubuntu-tw.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=234022#forumpost234022).

[This pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1017373/) contains the text of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, after changing from `tw.archive.ubuntu.com` to the main server.

Answer (score 2):

Open Update Manager. Click `Settings` (at the lower-left corner of the Update Manager window).

This opens the Software Sources settings. In the first (leftmost) tab, called `Ubuntu Software`, there is a drop down menu labeled `Download from:`. Change the server to another one. Then click the `Close` button, and try again to install `gcc`.

Since you have changed your Software Sources, to install packages from the command-line you might need to first run `sudo apt-get update`, before running any `sudo apt-get install ...` commands (like `sudo apt-get install build-essential`). *Thanks to [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) for pointing this out!*

Comment: @Eliah Kagan , Thanks for the editing . you're doing big help to me all the time .

Comment: I have changed the server, then try again. The following message is shown.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package build-essential

Comment: I have found the file /etc/apt/source.list and its content is pasted at paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: The URL of my paste are: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1017379/  and http://paste.ubuntu.com/1017373/

Comment: **Run** `sudo apt-get update` first!!! Then try installing `build-essential`. That's all you're missing.

Comment: @izx Excellent call. I should have mentioned that Raja's answer when I edited it before! (Editing to include it.)

Comment: @EliahKagan: how do you get Software Center to force an update, just curious - or does it happen automatically upon switching servers?

Comment: @EliahKagan: CLI help for `software-properties-gtk` says: `-n, --no-update       No update on repository change`, so we can assume it updates upon change by default.

Comment: Perhaps we haven't found the answer for Chi-Ping Lee yet after all. @Chi-PingLee Does it work for you if you run `sudo apt-get update` in the Terminal before trying again to install `build-essential`? If not, do you get different errors from what you had before?

Comment: It is work with following @izxś comment. Thanks all.